# Can an attacker guess my password length from a hash?

Tags: passwords, hash, brute-force, cryptanalysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible to detect password length from hash? Is doubling your password adds more security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29083/possible-to-detect-password-length-from-hash-is-doubling-your-password-adds-mor)

Considering I do not provide him any personal information relating to it, are there ways an attacker can guess how long my password is just by analyzing the hash?